# How can I set properties for ui Backbone element?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can I set properties (attributes) for "uploadButton"?

```
return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  ui: {
       "uploadButton": "ui-button green"
    }
});

this.ui.uploadButton. - and???
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onRender: function(){
   $(this.ui.uploadButton).attr('width', '500');
}
```

You can just easily select element by jQuery selector(or whatever) and add attribute by using attr() function.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Comment: Thanks :) Just added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Unless marionette does something odd, the backbone way of doing it is

```
return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  attributes: {
    width: "500"
  },
  ui: {
     "uploadButton": "ui-button green"
  }
});
```